# initWithCoder has been explicitly marked unavailable error using newest version of Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm seeing the following error during compile time when working with the latest version of Xamarin.iOS that was released yesterday:

> UIActivityViewController.h:23:1: note: 'initWithCoder:' has been
>   explicitly marked unavailable here
>           - (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder NS_UNAVAILABLE;

I don't recall ever having this issue before and my code hasn't changed much between the last update and now. Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41319) which is harder to diagnose because of a `clang` bug, i.e. it has nothing to do with `UIActivityViewController`.

You might be able to workaround this by removing `[Export ("initWithCoder:")]` inside your code. That should be fine unless your managed object needs to be created from native code. YMMV